# Trigger local notification for iOS - Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, localnotification

I am using this plugin and trying to trigger local notification for my Cordova iOS app with [Local notifications plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/0.7).

I dd following steps:

1. Installed plugin: `cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification@0.7.7`
2. Updated *config.xml*: `gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification"`
3. Added the following JavaScript in head tag for

*index.html*

```
plugin.notification.local.promptForPermission(function (granted) {
  alert("promptForPermission: "+granted);
});

plugin.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) {
  alert("hasPermission: "+granted);
});
```

4. Have a button in *index.html* to create a local notification after 5 secs.

Code for that looks like this:

```
function setLocalNotification()
{
  alert("from setLocalNotification");
  var t = new Date();
  t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 3);

  window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    title:   'Scheduled with delay',
    message: 'Test Message ',
    date:    t
  });

  alert("alert set");
 };
```

I do see a prompt for user's permission and the alert from hasPermission method shows the value as true. But I am still not able to get the actual local notification I am trying to set by clicking a button. I have already updated the *APPLocalNotification.m* file for the [this issue](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/281) by copying [this](https://github.com/pavoltanuska/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/commit/2e6ab6590c1ea703bd4ced3d0005bf4c7e7a4339) fix.

I don't see any more errors in the console log but I am still not able to trigger a local notification.

Comment: So the _alert_s on that function are both shown? Also, have you tried adding some more time before the notification should be shown? Or even better, try without the date option as then it should be shown instantly.

Comment: @sanfor yes both of the javascript alerts are executed and shown. I even tried without the date option as you suggested but no luck with that either.

Comment: Have you made sure that the _deviceReady_ event is triggered before you add the notification? Also you are using CLI to build this instead of PhoneGap Build, right? In the step 2 is completely unnecessary since it is only for PhoneGap Build apps.

Comment: @sanfor I have the  plugin.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) within the document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {...} and shows the hasPermission value as true. I am trying to set the local notification from an external function that needs to be executed on pressing a button. And yes I am using CLI to build and not phonegap build. I will update config.xml since that is not required. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I think I am also seeing the same issue, perhaps due to a recent iOS update? I only updated to iOS 8 very recently..

Comment: @nirvana I'm facing the same issue but I figure it out that despite the message doesn't appear, if you set the **"badge"** option in the ["window.plugin.notification.local.add"](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#schedule-local-notifications) method, the badge appears in the icon at home. I'll continue doing some more test to know how to show the msg. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the device is ready (       document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
) and also check if the plugin is correctly added $ cordova plugin ls.

Make sure you have "< script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">
" in your html .

Good luck!